# How do I do templated typed parameter specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I have the following code:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct e {

};

template <>
struct e<int N> {
    static const int value = N;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << e<5>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Which gives me a type mismatch. I realize that 5 is a r value so I'm guessing my solution could look like

```
e<int &&N>
```

but that doesn't work either. What can I do to generically implment this? Also am I using the terminology right callint `<int N>` a typed-template parameter where `<typename/class T>` is a non-typed template parameter?

Comment: You've got the terminology reversed `<int N>` is a non-type template parameter.

Comment: Please explain the downvote so I can improve my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have specified a typename for the primary template, you can't then specialize on the value of an int. Your primary template would have to be

```
template <int N> 
struct e
{ static const int value = N; };
```

And then you would be specializing on specific values. Of course for your example, assuming you only instaciante with `int` values, the above template is all that is needed, and no specialization at all.

However, assuming other types may be used, you can partially specialize on `std::integral_constant` or similar, which allows you to specialize on a type (that wraps the int value) instead.

Something like,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
struct e {

};

template <int N>
struct e<std::integral_constant<int,N> > {
    static const int value = N;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << e<std::integral_constant<int,5>>::value << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/1T1EJy)

Comment: Why do we need an integral_constant wrapper?

Comment: to make the value 5 into a type. 5 is not a type. 5 is a constant value of type int , and your primary template is expecting to be instanciated with a type, not a value.

Comment: Mmm, ok this is starting to make more sense. Tenplate overloading doesnt seem to happen at the template<> piece but only after struct __typename

Comment: Its all with respect to the primary template. If that expects 1 parameter that is a type, then your [partial] specializations must all come down to 1 parameter that is a type. In the case of a partial specialization, you can 'pull out' whatever you want (the specialization could have 10 parameters for example) as long as they are deduceable (in this case its an 'int' named 'N'. But the final combination (in the bit after the struct e<*this bit*>) must match what is expected by the primary template. In this case a single type.